# Oracle GRANT: prevent SQL injection

Tags: c#, oracle, sql-injection

I'm using Oracle from C# (Oracle Data Provider for .NET (ODP.NET) Core package). And I need to dynamically create users, assign roles, permissions etc. One of the tasks is to be able to **GRANT** roles and grants.

The question is - how in this case to prevent SQL injection? I can use parameters in select, update, delete, but can't use them here.

For example, when I create user, I validate it's name in Oracle using **sys.DBMS_ASSERT.simple_sql_name**. Can I do the same validation here? If no, what would be the approach?

Comment: I think assertion may also be not sufficient. What type of SQL injection you want to take care of? Grant/revoke/create user are already privileged operations. If you want to protect against any command other than grant/revoke/create user, then do not grant any other rights. If you want to restrict the list of users to be affected (for example, only users created from your app), then you may retrieve them via `select` with filter by bind variable and then perform operations.

Comment: Also, instead of executing the grant/revoke/create SQL directly from C#, build PL/SQL stored procedures to execute the actual commands using dynamic SQL with bind variables, then call the stored procedures from C#. That way there's no possibility of injecting anything extra into the mix or altering the code that performs the privileged operation. You have complete control of how users are created and provisioned.

Comment: @pmdba I think approach with stored procedures can help. Do you mind posting some example as an answer? 
We have an api to get, let's say, Oracle roles and another API which takes role as a parameter and assigns it to the user. In theory there can be posted anything.  So my query GRANT <anything> TO <user> can have injection, right?